# How can I line up the text inside a <span> following a <button>

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="xxx float-left">
   <button class="small">X</button>
   <button class="small">Y</button>
   <button class="small">Z</button>
   <span>xx</span>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS that's applied to these:

```
.xxx {
   line-height: 2.5rem;
}
button.small {
   font-size: 1.4rem;
   margin: 0 0.2rem;
   padding: 0.3rem 0.8rem;
   float: left;
}
.xxx span {
   line-height: 2.5rem;
}
```

I would like the `<span>` text to be lined up in the middle vertically but right now it appears at the top. Is there a way that I can make the xx text line up with the `button` labels?

Comment: Looks vertically centered to me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/593wP/

Comment: Yep. Vertically centered here as well. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/593wP/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AH3Hd/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox looked vertically aligned. For me, IE rendered it as you described.  I changed:

```
.xxx {
   line-height: 2.5rem;
}
```

to this:

```
.xxx {
   line-height: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Offhand I would not be using floats.

`Inline-block` was built for this:

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/DnE9z/)

```
button.small {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.xxx span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```